# Desktop shortcut to end a specific process

Tags: gui, shortcuts

Is there a way to create a desktop shortcut that will end a specific process in Ubuntu 18.04?
I tried the following .desktop file but nothing happens.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=EndConky
Exec=pkill -9 -u $USER conky
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Comment: Note: if you need to kill graphical application you can use `xkill` application. Does it suite your needs?

Comment: Just tried it. Yeah bash -c also works.

Comment: @dsstorefile1 Make that an answer, as this is appropriate way for such questions.

Comment: @Kizam The reason is didn't work is because `.desktop` files don't understand anything shell-related and don't have same environment as shell. In this case, variables like `$USER` are part of shells environment variables list.

Comment: Have you tried xkill?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, just created a new executable file with the kill command and linked to that in the .desktop file.

The name of the file doesn't matter but it must end in .desktop.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=EndConky
Exec=/usr/share/applications/killConky
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Name is just what you see once the file has been run and marked as trusted, this will only change when viewing the file in the GUI, the original .desktop filename will still show in the terminal.

Exec is the location of the file you want to run. It does not need to be in /usr/share/applications.

If Terminal is true the terminal will open when running the file.

The /usr/share/applications/killConky file contains the command that I want to run.
In this case:

```
pkill -9 -u $USER conky
```

I used $USER so it would still work with other users.

Its probably obvious but both the .desktop and exec files must be executable. To do this use chmod.

```
chmod 754 ~/Desktop/kill_conky.desktop
chmod 755 /usr/share/applications/killConky
```

Comment: Could you please add contents of `newFileLocation` and complete guide how to use it.

Comment: Sure thing, just added more info.